# Automated Partitioning with timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I want to partition my table (Oracle) automated on a daily basis.

I only have a Timestamp column given:

```
 DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS
```

So far I found this, but its not working:

```
create table 
pos_data ( 
    start_date        DATE,
    store_id          NUMBER,
    inventory_id      NUMBER(6),
    qty_sold          NUMBER(3),
 ) 
 PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date) 
 INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
 (  
  PARTITION pos_data_p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
  PARTITION pos_data_p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-8-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
 );
```

With this example I am getting Invalid Identifier error... and I dont know if a Timestamp makes a difference to a date column.

Answer:

```
create table 
pos_data_two ( 
    start_date        TIMESTAMP,
    store_id          NUMBER,
    inventory_id      NUMBER(6),
    qty_sold          NUMBER(3)
 ) 
 PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date) 
 INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL (1, 'DAY')) 
 (  
  PARTITION pos_data_p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
  PARTITION pos_data_p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-8-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have mistakenly placed a `,` after `qty_sold NUMBER(3),` Remove it and try like this,

```
create table 
pos_data ( 
    start_date        DATE,
    store_id          NUMBER,
    inventory_id      NUMBER(6),
    qty_sold          NUMBER(3)
 ) 
 PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date) 
 INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
 (  
  PARTITION pos_data_p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
  PARTITION pos_data_p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-8-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one comma to many (after `qty_sold` column definition):

```
create table 
pos_data ( 
    start_date        DATE,
    store_id          NUMBER,
    inventory_id      NUMBER(6),
    qty_sold          NUMBER(3)
 ) 
 PARTITION BY RANGE (start_date) 
 INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH')) 
 (  
  PARTITION pos_data_p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
  PARTITION pos_data_p3 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-8-2007', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
 );
```

Comment: True, and I changed the function to NUMTODSINTERVAL, that should work for a daily partition